# How to redirect to another page using javascript after successful login?

Tags: javascript

I need to have a login form that validates and after login the page needs to redirect to a html page. I also need to hard code in a username and password so only with the correct user name/password the page will redirect. If it doesn't have the correct user/pass then I need an alert.

I've tried a bunch of variations but I know I missing something or using the code wrong. Please help! :) Thanks!
This is my code so far.

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
    'use strict';

    // Get references to the form elements:
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');

    // Validate the login
    if ((email.value.length > 0) && (password.value.length > 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please complete the form!');
        return false;
    }
}

function check(form) {

    var emailArray = ("myemail@live.com", "");
    var passwordArray = ("MyLogIn", "");

    if (email.value == "email" && password.value == "password") {
        window.open('myaccount.html');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter correct username or password!');
        return false;
    }   
}

function init() {
    'use strict';

    // Confirm that document.getElementById() can be used:
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var loginForm = document.getElementById('lgform');
        loginForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="lgform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="submit"></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that what you are trying to do is **very** insecure. No authentication logic should be done in the client side. Anyone can just look at your source code and see all the user names and passwords easily.

Comment: I hope that this code will not be appear in production.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  You need to process the login on the server side and issue an appropriate HTTP response if the login is successful.  Most likely an HTTP 302.

Comment: Homework question I'm guessing.

Comment: The hard coding will not appear in production.

Comment: Please help! I still don't know what I'm doing wrong and I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding the username and password client side is very dangerous - **don't do it**.

In order to redirect you simply:

`window.location = "http://www.google.com/"`

however I very much doubt the page you are directing too is secure, can it be accessed directly via the url without passing your authentication?